# Can I generate a configuration file for my python app with distutils?

Tags: python, supervisord

I have created a python app that will run as a service managed by supervisord.

The problem is that I need the configuration file for supervisord customized at install time. The configuration file contains arguments to the app, and those arguments will include paths to files that will be decided (via command line arguments) at install time. There are other arguments that should also be decided at install time as well.

I would like to have the conf file include 'macro' values that will be replaced at install time when the conf file is copied to its destination

For example, suppose I have a conf file template like 'myapp.conf.template':

```
[program:myapp]
command=python APP_INSTALL_LOCATION --log_file=LOG_FILE_PATH
user=EXECUTING_USER
```

And I would like it to generate a myapp.conf that looks like this after install:

```
[program:myapp]
command=python /usr/local/myapp --log_file=/var/log/myapp.log
user=dusktreader
```

I would like those replacements to be based on command line parameters to setup.py

I have tried googling for this and haven't had much luck.
Can anyone give me a starting point for researching this?

Comment: Would ConfigParser be helpful for you?

Comment: No, I don't need to parse the config file. The supervisord application uses it. I just need it to be customized at install time

Answer (score 1):

You can use a templating language such as [`Jinja2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2) to read the template and generate a new file that can be customised at install time:

```
# These values can be read from a file or environment variables
template_kwargs = {
    'logging_root': '/path/to/logging/'
    'program_name': 'example',
}
with open(path_conf_template) as conf_template:
    template = jinja2.Template(conf_template.read())
    with open(path_conf, 'w') as conf_template_output:
        conf_template_output.write(template.render(**template_kwargs))
```

and in the template you can construct values with variables:

```
stdout_logfile={{ logging_root }}{{ program_name }}.log
```

This means you can use the Jinja2 templating language with for loops and other logic in the template as well.